# Create new Instance of Child Class

Tags: java, class, inheritance, instance, children

I have an array list of Enemies and each enemy kind extends enemy. Now I don't wan't every same enemy kind to share all their stats, but I base my enemy selection of another array list. So I think the way to go would be to get the object of the array list containing all the options and then changing them to new Instances of the same class. My question is, how would I do that? Or do you guys have a better approach?

For easy of understanding here's what I mean abstracted

```
class shop{
   ArrayList<Enemy> allEnemies;
}

class generator{
  ArrayList<Enemies> selectedToGenerate = based on some of allEnemies

  for(Enemy x : selectedToGenerate){ // i know this wouldn't work
    x = newInstanceOf(x.getNonenemyThereforeChildclassClass());
  }
}
```

hope this explains what I mean. Appreciate your time!

Comment: So `Enemy` is the base class and you have subclasses like `EnemyA`, `EnemyB` etc in that list? And you want basically a copy of the list, but with new instances?

Comment: It is important: do you plan to add new Enemy kind to your application? Could you provide example how do you use enemies. I am thinking about two patterns: `Factory` and `Builder`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `Builder` to your `Enemy`.

```
abstract class Enemy {
   private int strength;
   public Builder<Enemy> getBuilder();
   public static class Builder<T extends Enemy> {
       int str;
       public Builder<T> copyValues(T enemy) {
           str = enemey.strength;
           return this;
       }
       public Builder<T> strength(int s) {
           str = s;
           return this;
       }
       protected void fillValues(T toFill) {
           toFill.strength = str;
       }
       protected abstract T createInstance();
       public T build() {
           T result = createInstance();
           fillValues(result);
           return result;
       }
   }
}
```

This `Builder` can create instances of your `Enemy` and fill it with values. For subclasses, you can extend the `Builder` by allowing it to fill more values.

```
class EnemyA extends EnemyA {
    private int speed;
    public Builder<EnemyA> getBuilder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    class EnemyABuilder extends Builder<EnemyA> {
        int speed;
        public EnemyABuilder copyValues(EnemyA enemy) {
            super.copyValues(enemy);
            speed = enemy.speed;
        }
        public EnemyABuilder speed(int s) {
            speed = s;
            return this;
        }
        protected void fillValues(EnemyA toFill) {
            super.fillValues(toFill);
            toFill.speed = speed;
        }
        protected EnemyA createInstance() {
            return new EnemyA();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can create copies of the enemies by using their builders:

```
for(Enemy x : selectedToGenerate){ // i know this wouldn't work
    Builder<? extends Enemy> builder = x.getBuilder();
    builer.copyValues(x);
    Enemy copy = builder.build();
}
```

As an additional bonus, you can use the builder to quickly create different versions of the same enemy.

```
EnemyA.Builder base = new Builder().strength(10);
EnemyA withSpeed1 = base.speed(1).build();
EnemyA withSpeed2 = base.speed(2).build();    
EnemyA withSpeed3 = base.speed(3).build();
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much! Admittedly, I am not yet the best Java Programmer, as sad as it is. Still I really look forward into understanding builders, but thanks to your solution, i will add a map as a quick fix for now. Really appreciate your help :)